# How to use & and | signs in macro_rules pattern

Tags: rust, macro-rules

I'm trying to write a simple macro like this, to facilitate the writing of my code

```
enum Term {
    Or(Box<Term>, Box<Term>),
    And(Box<Term>, Box<Term>),
    Value(u8),
}

macro_rules! term {
    ($value_1:expr & $value_2:expr) => {
        Term::And(Box::new($value_1), Box::new($value_2))
    };
    ($value_1:expr | $value_2: expr) => {
        Term::Or(Box::new($value_1), Box::new($value_2))
    };
    ($value: expr) => {
        Term::Value($value)
    };
}
```

However, I cannot put a `&` or `|` after an `expr` in my pattern. I tried using `tt`, but it didn't work because I'm not always just putting one token in my `$value`. `pat_param` doesn't seem to work with `&` either.
The only option that seems to work would be to use `(($value_1:expr) & ($value_2:expr))`, but if I could do without the extra parentheses, it'd be better.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` isn't allowed to avoid [ambiguity](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#follow-set-ambiguity-restrictions), there is no way to have `&` as a token directly after an `expr` parameter in a declarative macro.

> `expr` and `stmt` may only be followed by one of: `=>`, `,`, or `;`.

Comment: All my possible values are always `x`, `x.clone()`, `x.method()` or those kind of expressions. Are there any other capture type that might work for those?

Comment: @er1t Is `x` an arbitrary expression?

Comment: I think either a [procedual macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html) or using parentheses are your best options.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `x` is a simple variable (of type `Term` or `u8`). It's never used in a complex expression, it's always just one single variable.

Comment: @cafce25 procedural macro seems a bit overkill in my situation, so I'm gonna stick to the parentheses! Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to allow a single variable, optionally with a method call after, you can use the following macro (note it does not handle generic method call syntax):

```rust
macro_rules! term {
    (
        $name:ident $( .$method:ident( $($argument:expr),* $(,)? ) )?
        $($rest:tt)+
    ) => {
        term!(@parsed_lhs
            ( $name $( .$method( $($argument),* ) )? )
            $($rest)*
        )
    };
    (@parsed_lhs $value_1:tt & $value_2:expr) => {
        Term::And(Box::new($value_1), Box::new($value_2))
    };
    (@parsed_lhs $value_1:tt | $value_2:expr) => {
        Term::Or(Box::new($value_1), Box::new($value_2))
    };
    ($value:expr) => {
        Term::Value($value)
    };
}
```

This macro is not perfect, it has some edge cases, but it should be good enough.